# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraints must be a GridBagConstraint

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, illegalargumentexception

Im righting a simple text based game for my computing coursework but I'm having a few problems grasping how to use the AWT `GridBagLayout` and `GridBagConstraints`.

When ever I run the code i get this error message:

[image]

Here is a copy of my GUI code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class GUI extends JFrame
{

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI()
    {

        JFrame AG = new JFrame("Adventure Game");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        setResizable(true);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p=new JPanel();
        p.setLayout (new GridBagLayout());

        AG.add(p);
        GridBagConstraints GBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        AG.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton saveButton =new JButton("Save");
        JButton loadButton =new JButton("Load");
        JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");

        JLabel textBox= new JLabel("Story line will go here.");

        JLabel label11 = new JLabel("Test 1");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 1;
        p.add(label11,AG);
        JLabel label12 = new JLabel("Test 2");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 2;
        p.add(label12,AG);
        JLabel label13 = new JLabel("Test 3");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 3;
        p.add(label13,AG);
        JLabel label14 = new JLabel("Test 4");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 4;
        p.add(label14,AG);

        add(p);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is me trying to use `GridBagConstraints` without using `GridBagLayout` but I'm quite new to java so don't how to use `GridBagLayout` to fix the problem, most of this code is from various different tutorials I've watched on youtube, but not copied just taking how various people do it and trying to mix it badly

Thanks for the help
- Tom

Comment: Please post your stack trace in a code block, makes it easier to read

Comment: Also, your `main`method must be `static`.

Comment: What do you mean? Is that a setting on the pastern and sorry I'm quite new to all of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Main Problem

You are passing `AG`, which is an instance of `JFrame` as the constraint when adding your components...

```
p.add(label11, AG);
```

Instead, you should be using `GBC`...

```
p.add(label11, GBC);
```

## Other problems...

Your `GUI` is extending from `JFrame`, but you are creating an instance of another `JFrame` within in, this is very confusing...

It is normally recommended that you don't extend from top level containers, like `JFrame`, as you're not really adding an new value to the class and it locks you into a single container, reducing the reusability of your UI's

Instead, stick with the new instance of a `JFrame` (`AG`)...

```
public class GUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    public GUI() {

        JFrame AG = new JFrame("Adventure Game");
        AG.setResizable(true);
        AG.setVisible(true);
        AG.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //...
```

---

You should really call `setVisible` last, after you have build the core interface, this will reduce potential issues with the way that the API updates the components

```
    public GUI() {

        JFrame AG = new JFrame("Adventure Game");
        AG.setResizable(true);
        AG.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //...
        AG.setVisible(true);
    }
```

---

This...

```
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

is a horrible way to maximise a window, just use [`JFrame#setExtendedState`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)) and pass it `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH`...

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

---

You should learn and use the common naming conventions of the lanuage, have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

---

Swing has some important rules, one of which is to ensure that you always create and modify your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

```
public GUI() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            new GUI();
        }
    });
}
```

See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

---

You main method should be declared as `static`, for example...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

otherwise the class will not be runnable as a main entry point for Java

Comment: Thank you so much its fixed now :P, I've only just started at looking at the Swing stuff today so my brain's bit scrambled i should probably use slightly more distinctive names aha.

Should I re-upload a paste bin of it fixed so other people with similar problems can look?

Comment: Not unless my answer didn't solve the issue.  Changing the code makes it difficult to determine if the original question matches their problem and if the answer actually answers the question ;)

Comment: Ok thanks :P and thank you for all your help its saved me another hour of puzzling over why it won't work aha, do you know of any good java books on swing that I could buy that might help my learning?

Comment: Not really, not anymore.  I'd always recommend filthy rich clients, but that might be a little over your head right now.  You could always start with [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: Really sorry to be such a pain :P but when i added the  AG.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
it came up with these two errors :

Error:(29, 37) java: /Users/thomasthorburn/Documents/Adventure Game/src/GUI.java:29: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable EXIT_ON_CLOSE
location: class GUI

and

Error:(61, 9) java: /Users/thomasthorburn/Documents/Adventure Game/src/GUI.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method add(javax.swing.JPanel)
location: class GUI

Comment: Try using `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` and `AG.add`

Comment: The AG.add worked but the JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE didn't it says that it's not a statement.

Comment: Ohhh ok, opps ;) I really can't thank you enough for your help you've been a million times better then my teacher, how did you learn java so well?

Comment: Lots and lots of late nights and trying things, reading tutorials and blog posts

Comment: Oh ok, Ill try doing that, I've got the late nights part down to a tea ;) its 00:30 in England aha. Thanks again for all your help! :D